# objective C function used in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Hello I am currently using an objective C library which is working great, however, in one of the functions the variable is Class. In swift this becomes AnyClass. What I am trying to do is add a class in this case a custom Item class as Item.self() but it does not allow me since it says it needs to be of type AnyClass. Any ideas why Any won't accept any but specifically Any? Thank you!

OBJ C:

```
-(void)getItemDetails:(Class)clazz withPath:(NSString*)path{
//some code
}
```

Swift:

```
self.getItemDetails(Item.self(), path: mainItem.path)
```

Comment: can you try to use Item.classForCoder, this should work because classForCoder is AnyClass.

Comment: @DamyanTodorov works like a charm! Thank you!